# Grails convert string to letter case

Tags: grails, groovy

I need to convert string to letter case (proper case or title case), is there any default function on Groovy support for this or I need to manual sub string convert first character?

Answer (score 11):

```
assert org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils.capitalizeFully('man OF stEEL') == 'Man Of Steel'
```

The `WordUtils` class is provided by Apache Commons Lang, which is available on the classpath of Grails apps by defatult

Answer (score 6):

Until i know there is no such a function or method but i use to do it with this sentence

```
assert "John Doe" == "john dOE".tokenize(" ")*.toLowerCase()*.capitalize().join(" ")
```

I hope it help you

Comment: or using `split()` as `"john doe".split()*.capitalize().join(" ")`

Comment: This will only capitalize the first letter of each word, e.g. it won't work for `'JOHN DOE'`

Comment: He can very well use `.toLowerCase()` before split/tokenize. But using Apache commons lang shows less verbosity and can be easily used. :) This can be an example if anybody does not want to involve Apache Commons Lang lib.

Comment: setting .toLowerCase() is a good observation, it actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can use the  method capitalize()

http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#capitalize%28%29

Comment: This only capitalizes the first letter of a String, rather than converting an entire String to title case

Comment: Surely, only first letter.

Answer (score -2):

I got it, here is solution for those who needed

```
def capitalize(s) { s[0].toUpperCase() + s[1..-1].toLowerCase() }
caps = "man OF stEEL".replaceAll(/\w+/) { w -> capitalize(w) }
```

Comment: You are the one that "closes this topic". Click the little check mark next to your answer if it is the correct answer to your question.